# Retrieve json from database and display in html form in symfony4.3

Tags: symfony

I want to retrieve JSON data from database and display it the form(twig 
file).
My form has various text fields.My question is how to display values in text field relevant to that text field.I am new to symfony and even new to programming.Please guide me,should I use Javascript for this??  Please help.

```
This is my twig file--

{% for key in id %}
<form>
<div><h3>入　居　申　込　書　 (法人用)</h3></div>
    <fieldset>          
      <label>物件名:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="1" value="{{key.id}}">
        <label >号室:</label>)
   <input type="text" name="roomNumber" id="2" value=" 
{{key.applicationNo}}">


This is my controller--
class ListPageController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/list/page/{id}", name="list_page",methods="GET")
 */
public function index($id)
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(NewEntity::class);

    $em = $repository->findAll();
    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

   $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
   $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($em, 'json');
   var_dump(json_decode($jsonContent));
   var_dump(json_decode($jsonContent,true,2));

   return $this->render('list_page/index.html.twig', 
  ['id'=>$jsonContent]);

    }  
  }


  I am getting output like this--
  array(18) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#565 (5) { ["id"]=> int(1) 
  ["applicationNo"]=> int(201) ["dataJson"]=> string(5) "Hello" 
  ["careteTime"]=> object(stdClass)#558 (3) { ["timezone"]=> 
  object(stdClass)#548 (3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "UTC" ["transitions"]=> 
  array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#556 (5) { ["ts"]=> 
  int(-9223372036854775808) ["time"]=> string(33) "-292277022657-01- 
  27T08:29:52+0000" ["offset"]=> int(0) ["isdst"]=> bool(false) ["abbr"]=> 
  string(3) "UTC" } } ["location"]=> object(stdClass)#557 (4) { 
  ["country_code"]=> string(2) "??" ["latitude"]=> int(0) ["longitude"]=> 
  int(0) ["comments"]=> string(0) "" } } ["offset"]=> int(0) ["timestamp"]=> 
  int(1566800940) } ["updateTime"]=> object(stdClass)#562 (3) { 
  ["timezone"]=> object(stdClass)#559 (3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "UTC" 
  ["transitions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#560 (5) { ["ts"]=> 
  int(-9223372036854775808) ["time"]=> string(33) "-292277022657-01- 
  27T08:29:52+0000" ["offset"]=> int(0) ["isdst"]=> bool(false) ["abbr"]=> 
  string(3) "UTC" } } ["location"]=> object(stdClass)#561 (4) { 
  ["country_code"]=> string(2) "??" ["latitude"]=> int(0) ["longitude"]=> 
  int(0) ["comments"]=> string(0) "" } } ["offset"]=> int(0) ["timestamp"]=> 
  int(1566800940) } } [1]=> object(stdClass)#563 (5) { ["id"]=> int(2) 
  ["applicationNo"]=> int(201) ["dataJson"]=> string(50) " 
  {"name":"jshjs","roomNumber":"nxns","lay":"nxmsm"}" ["careteTime"]=> 
  object(stdClass)#551 (3) { ["timezone"]=> object(stdClass)#564 (3) { 
  ["name"]=> string(3) "UTC" ["transitions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
  object(stdClass)#549 (5) { ["ts"]=> int(-9223372036854775808) ["time"]=> 
  string(33) "-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000" ["offset"]=> int(0) 
  ["isdst"]=> bool(false) ["abbr"]=> string(3) "UTC" } } ["location"]=> 
  object(stdClass)#550 (4) { ["country_code"]=> string(2) "??" 
   ["latitude"]=> int(0) ["longitude"]=> int(0) ["comments"]=> string(0) "" 
  } } ["offset"]=> int(0) ["timestamp"]=> int(1566802183) } ["updateTime"]=>
```

Comment: First, you should think about another name than "id" for your variable ;-). Then, to make your dump more clear, you could use "echo '<pre>' , var_dump($variable) , '</pre>';" to display one value per line. If you want to dump from twig just use {{ dump(id) }}.

Comment: echo '<pre>' , var_dump($variable) , '</pre>';you want me to put this in controller instead of return statement?